# SQL Server 2016 deadlock issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, deadlock, database-deadlocks

In one of my production environment, I am seeing deadlocks on daily basis. Please help me out to fix the issue.

Enabled traceflag and captured deadlock graph. Tried to understand the graph and I suspect it is causing self blocking, due to which deadlocks are happening.

But still not able to figure out the solution to avoid the deadlocks. Please find the below deadlock graph.

```
Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s               process id=process61ba9be4e8 taskpriority=0 logused=3428 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057606263406592 (a25f616f2d23) waittime=4405 ownerId=10237242845 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T14:26:40.190 XDES=0x7fc9cfd8a8 lockMode=U schedulerid=8 kpid=1848 status=suspended spid=87 sbid=10 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T14:26:42.463 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T14:26:41.317 lastattention=2023-02-20T14:26:09.710 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVWF2 hostpid=3948 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10237242845 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                   

Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=190 stmtend=4976 sqlhandle=0x020000003a4798176d72f68ef07ce824c0a2e9b7e4cc607c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s                 frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         


Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s            (@0 int,@1 tinyint,@2 nvarchar(40),@3 nvarchar(20),@4 int,@5 int,@6 nvarchar(20),@7 int,@8 int)SELECT  TOP (@0) "timestamp","Table ID","For Type","For No_","For Version No_","For Doc_ No_ Occ_","Entry No_","Archiving Date","Archived","Description","Archive-Reference No_","Document Type","Date of Creation","Created by User ID","Enclosure Type","File Name","Batch archived","Original Archive-Reference No_","Version No_","Vendor No_","Customer No_","Employee No_","Job No_","Contact No_","Document No_","Document Date","Purchase Request No_","Purchase Order No_","Archive Comment","External Document No","Vendor _ Customer _ Staff Name","Applicant No_","Application No_","Responsibility Center","Advertisement No_","Position No_","Web Application No_",
"Application Doc_ Type","Create by",DATALENGTH("Attachment uploaded by User"),"To Delete","Visible to Finance","E-Mail Recipient ID","E-Mail Type","Send E-Mail","Date E-Mail Send","E-Mail Sender ID","CC E-Mail Address","Visible to Supervisor" FROM "mahi_live".dbo."E                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s               process id=process6412507468 taskpriority=0 logused=3580 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057606257704960 (658c8490e1b5) waittime=5312 ownerId=10237243795 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T14:26:41.493 XDES=0x8afb9358a8 lockMode=U schedulerid=10 kpid=16080 status=suspended spid=192 sbid=3 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T14:26:41.560 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T14:26:41.557 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.557 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVST2 hostpid=1940 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10237243795 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                 

Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=70 stmtend=410 sqlhandle=0x020000004fde700720dfe565223b7b3cf429c5d70cde3c2c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  



Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s               keylock hobtid=72057606263406592 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$Archived Enclosure indexname=$4 id=lock7e01c59c80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057606263406592                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      




Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid24s               keylock hobtid=72057606257704960 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$Archived Enclosure indexname=ISO$Archived Enclosure$0 id=lock67604ecc00 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057606257704960                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                





Feb 20 2023  2:26PM          spid87            Transaction (Process ID 87) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             



Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid93            Transaction (Process ID 93) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             



Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s               process id=process7a3b64b848 taskpriority=0 logused=118616 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057604492034048 (f91127006dd9) waittime=2783 ownerId=10238775088 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T14:53:47.360 XDES=0x7835dce408 lockMode=U schedulerid=9 kpid=6712 status=suspended spid=93 sbid=8 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T14:53:47.697 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T14:53:47.693 lastattention=2023-02-20T14:53:47.627 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVST1 hostpid=3032 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10238775088 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                  

Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=2646 sqlhandle=0x0200000036795c3b89c13ff7610703fae5396babbbeb432e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              


Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s            SELECT  TOP (1) "timestamp","Entry No_","G_L Account No_","Posting Date","Document Type","Document No_","Description","Bal_ Account No_","Amount","Global Dimension 1 Code","Global Dimension 2 Code","User ID","Source Code","System-Created Entry","Prior-Year Entry","Job No_","Quantity","VAT Amount","Business Unit Code","Journal Batch Name","Reason Code","Gen_ Posting Type","Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group","Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group","Bal_ Account Type","Transaction No_","Debit Amount","Credit Amount","Document Date","External Document No_","Source Type","Source No_","No_ Series","Tax Area Code","Tax Liable","Tax Group Code","Use Tax","VAT Bus_ Posting Group","VAT Prod_ Posting Group","Additional-Currency Amount","Add_-Currency Debit Amount","Add_-Curre
ncy Credit Amount","Close Income Statement Dim_ ID","IC Partner Code","Reversed","Reversed by Entry No_","Reversed Entry No_","Dimension Set ID","Prod_ Order No_","FA Entry Type","FA Entry No_","Fund No_","Fund Year","Order No_","Request No_","Original Fund Year","Post P                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s               process id=process7229c13848 taskpriority=0 logused=1191196 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057604514578432 (09d4527897de) waittime=2473 ownerId=10238773287 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T14:53:42.643 XDES=0x717cb88e58 lockMode=U schedulerid=6 kpid=11096 status=suspended spid=70 sbid=7 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T14:53:48.007 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T14:53:47.887 lastattention=1900-01-01T00:00:00.887 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVST1 hostpid=3628 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10238773287 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                

Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=16 stmtend=2132 sqlhandle=0x0200000029916b1847fc62b742f89668390cc10a94a50f4a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s                 frame procname=unknown line=1 sqlhandle=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         


Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s            (@0 int)SELECT  TOP (@0) "timestamp","Entry No_","Contact No_","Contact Company No_","Date","Description","Information Flow","Initiated By","Attachment No_","Cost (LCY)","Duration (Min_)","User ID","Interaction Group Code","Interaction Template Code","Campaign No_","Campaign Entry No_","Campaign Response","Campaign Target","Segment No_","Evaluation","Time of Interaction","Attempt Failed","To-do No_","Salesperson Code","Delivery Status","Canceled","Correspondence Type","Contact Alt_ Address Code","Logged Segment Entry No_","Document Type","Document No_","Version No_","Doc_ No_ Occurrence","Contact Via","Send Word Docs_ as Attmt_","Interaction Language Code","E-Mail Logged","Subject","Opportunity No_","Postponed","For Version No_","Show in Staf
f Documents","Show in OBSOLETE","Show in Employee Profile Card","For Date","User Sent by Email on","System Sent by Email on","Archived Encl_ Ref_ No_","Table ID","For Type","For No_" FROM "mahi_live".dbo."ISO$Interaction Log Entry" WITH(UPDLOCK)  ORDER BY "Entry No_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s               keylock hobtid=72057604492034048 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$G_L Entry indexname=ISO$G_L Entry$0 id=lock7e00c5c580 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057604492034048                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  




Feb 20 2023  2:53PM          spid32s               keylock hobtid=72057604514578432 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$Interaction Log Entry indexname=ISO$Interaction Log Entry$0 id=lock6253cfbe80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057604514578432                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          





Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid131            Transaction (Process ID 131) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           



Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s               process id=process8bce02f848 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057607488798720 (e1784bd73cba) waittime=3021 ownerId=10240329240 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T15:26:59.983 XDES=0x78e9734408 lockMode=U schedulerid=3 kpid=11988 status=suspended spid=131 sbid=3 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T15:27:00.117 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T15:27:00.113 lastattention=2023-02-20T15:24:43.120 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVST1 hostpid=3832 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10240329240 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                     

Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtend=386 sqlhandle=0x020000002da602149c252a158be60b3435ca91002350b7870000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               


Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s            SELECT  TOP (1) "timestamp","User-ID","Tasks","GUID","Parked Tasks","Tasks RTC" FROM "mahi_live".dbo."ISO$Work Flow Tasks" WITH(UPDLOCK)  ORDER BY "User-ID" ASC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s               process id=process8bce05f088 taskpriority=0 logused=5764164 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057607488798720 (0af84e5906f3) waittime=2467 ownerId=10240326023 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2023-02-20T15:26:49.937 XDES=0x8bb1428598 lockMode=U schedulerid=9 kpid=14312 status=suspended spid=63 sbid=5 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2023-02-20T15:27:00.093 lastbatchcompleted=2023-02-20T15:27:00.093 lastattention=2023-02-20T15:26:49.910 clientapp=Microsoft Dynamics NAV Service hostname=HQNAVWF2 hostpid=4792 loginname=ADS\xsnavsvctier isolationlevel=repeatable read (3) xactid=10240326023 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=10000 clientoption1=671156320 clientoption2=128056                                                                

Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s                 frame procname=adhoc line=1 stmtstart=74 stmtend=532 sqlhandle=0x020000009108fb25da5f10d40f7178eeb397a4774fbfdadc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  


Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s            (@0 nvarchar(50),@1 uniqueidentifier)SELECT "timestamp","User-ID","Tasks","GUID","Parked Tasks","Tasks RTC" FROM "mahi_live".dbo."ISO$Work Flow Tasks" WITH(UPDLOCK)  WHERE ("User-ID">@0 AND "GUID"<>@1) ORDER BY "User-ID" ASC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN, FAST 50)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s               keylock hobtid=72057607488798720 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$Work Flow Tasks indexname=ISO$Work Flow Tasks$0 id=lock6823d52080 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057607488798720                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      




Feb 20 2023  3:27PM          spid24s               keylock hobtid=72057607488798720 dbid=6 objectname=mahi_live.dbo.ISO$Work Flow Tasks indexname=ISO$Work Flow Tasks$0 id=lock88679c1d80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057607488798720
```

Comment: Open the deadlock graph (.xdl file) in [Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/new-deadlock-visualizations-in-sql-sentry-and-plan-explorer) (which is a [free download](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer#hs_cos_wrapper_widget_1593613195478)).

Comment: why are you select'ing with UPDLOCK

Comment: The Repeatable Read isolation level increases likelihood of deadlocks. Note deadlock reports are already available in the `system_health` extended event trace without the need  to turn on trace flags.